# The left-hand side of an assignment must be a variable, property or indexer

Tags: c#

I'm getting an error and I don't know why:

```
static void decoupeTableau(IEnumerable<int> dst, IEnumerable<int> src)
{
    for (int i = 0; i < src.Count() && i < 4; ++i)
        dst.ElementAt(i) = src.ElementAt(i); // Here
}
```

Error:

> The left-hand side of an assignment must be a variable, property or indexer

Why I'm getting it?

Comment: `dst.ElementAt(i)` will return you a value for example number `42` and then you are trying to assign it some new value. Plus see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5595955/possible-to-overwrite-items-in-ienumerablet-using-reflection

Comment: I think what you want outside of this method is `dst = src.Take(4).Concat(dst.Skip(Math.Min(4, src.Count())));`

Comment: The error says what is the problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Why I'm getting it ?

Because you've got an assignment operator where the left hand side is a method call. What did you expect that to do? What code would that call? An assigment has to either set the value of a variable, or call a setter for a property. This isn't doing either of those things.

Basically, you can't do this - and for `IEnumerable<T>` it doesn't even make sense, as it can be read-only, generated etc.

Perhaps you want an `IList<int>` instead:

```
static void DecoupeTableau(IList<int> dst, IEnumerable<int> src)
{ 
    int i = 0;
    foreach (var value in src.Take(4))
    {
        dst[i] = value;
        i++;
    }
}
```

Note how this code is also potentially *much* more efficient - calling `Count()` and `ElementAt` in a loop can be very expensive. (For example, with a generator, each time you call `Count()` you have to iterate over the *whole* stream - so it wouldn't even complete if this were a theoretically infinite stream, such as a random sequence of integers.)

Comment: "Because you've got an assignment operator where the left hand side is a method call" - why is that a problem when the method returns an object?

Comment: @Sipo: I'm not sure why you think it *wouldn't* be a problem. The result of a method call is a value, not a variable. You can't assign to a value - what would that even mean? Possibly related: the method doesn't return an object. It returns a reference. Nothing ever returns an actual object. Every expression classified as a value is either a value type value or a reference (or a pointer).

Comment: If it returns a reference, wouldn't `Method() = new Something()` mean that this reference now refers to a different object?

Comment: @Sipo: It's still not clear to me what you'd expect that to do. *Which* reference now refers to a different object? Are you suggesting that if I return the value of a private field (say a `string` reference) from a method, the caller should be able to change the value of my field to refer to a different string? Very definitely not...

Comment: I believe I understand the problem now. Thank you!

Comment: @Sipo: Phew - it's one of those things that's really hard to explain until the light bulb goes off!

Answer (score 0):

The thing with the IEnumerable is that you can loop thru the items but not change the list. If you need to actually change the list you need IList or array or similar.

The error you are getting is because ElemetAt is a function, not the element itself.

Also it is a particularly bad idea to loop thru IEnumerable with a for loop, you need a foreach loop instead.